# как скрестить график csv с графической отрисовкой?

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени, есть данные [XAUUSD.csv](http://wdfiles.ru/6poy)
и две написанные подпрограммы, необходимо чтобы выводился график свечей по данным из файла

```
data= pd.read_csv(r'XAUUSD.csv', encoding='cp1252',header = 0, sep= ',')

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
for col in df.columns: 
    if 'Volume' in col: 
        del df[col] 
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('сюда засунуть свечи', fontsize=22)
plt.show()
```

по условию отрисовки свечей по коду снизу,

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
color = 'white'

Open=80
Height=250 
Low=10
Close=190
T1=100  #время свечи
z=20 #ширина свечи

c = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='white')
c.pack()

c.create_line(T1, Low, T1,Height,width=3)

if Open<Close: 
    c.create_rectangle(T1-z, Open, T1+z, Close, fill='white', outline='black',
                    width=3, activedash=(5, 4))
else : 
    c.create_rectangle(T1-z, Open, T1+z, Close, fill='black', outline='black',
                    width=3, activedash=(5, 4))

root.mainloop()
```

плюс знает ли кто нибудь как прописать условие что при определенном кол-ве свечей, допустим более 300 на экране снизу появлялся бы бегунок прокрутки(так как данных из файла может быть порядка 300 000 свечей)?

Comment: Мне кажется тут не прокрутка, тут пейджинг нужен.

Comment: https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/